# Bring all items back in an array after using splice() to remove them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array of some strings. When I click on a button, the second item of that array is removed using splice(2, 1). When I click on the second button I want to bring those removed items back so that the array becomes what it was like before. How can I do that? What if I remove all the items from the array using splice and then I want to bring them back?

```
    //html
    <button onclick="removeFunc()" id="removeBtn">Remove 2nd Item</button>
    <button id="addBtn">Add Removed Elements</button>

    //js
    const addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
    const removeBtn = document.getElementById('removeBtn');
    var arr = ['hello', 'howdy', 'word', 'animal'];

    function removeFunc(){
            arr.splice(2, 1);
    }
```

Now, I want a function which can bring those removed elements back. Please Help Me!

Comment: [`splice` returns the deleted elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value).

Comment: Can you tell me how? Please.

Comment: splice returns the removed items, you can save them and use splice again to add them back to original array

Comment: Part of programming, and learning to be a good programmer, is using logic to puzzle things out. Trying things, seeing how they fail, trying something different, etc.. If I just give you the answer, you will be denied that opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the spliced items and add the items later.

```js
function showItems() {
    document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = array.join(', ');
}

function removeItems() {
    removed.push(...array.splice(1, 1));
    showItems();
}

function addItems() {
    array.push(...removed);
    removed.length = 0;
    showItems();
}

var array = ['hello', 'howdy', 'word', 'animal'],
    removed = [];
    
    showItems();
```

```html
<button onclick="removeItems()" id="removeBtn">Remove 2nd Item</button>
<button onclick="addItems()" id="addBtn">Add Removed Elements</button><br>
<p id="items"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .splice() removes an item from the original array, you can simply ignore the return value from .splice() and use the original array.

For example where you have this:

```
 newArray = arr.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, arr),1);
  console.log(newArray);
```

Instead it would be this:

```
 arr.splice( $.inArray(itemtoRemove,arr), 1 );
  console.log(arr);
```